# where is the local resolver?

Tags: network, internet, dns

I'm looking into dns cache poisoning and  I was confused as to where the local resolver was located.

From what I understand the local resolver is located in a DNS server where we perform lookups when the IP address to the domain is not found in the local cache of the current system from where we send a REQ.

When looking online it seems that the local resolver is not a server but instead a software put in a server that takes charge of DNS requests (https://wiki.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Local_DNS_resolver). I was wondering in that case that if it is a software then it could thus be downloaded on the computer and the computer itself could be a local resolver.

I'm sorry if this question is not too clear but to sum up. I would like to know what and where the local resolver is located.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI lasyer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [security.se].

Comment: @RonMaupin apologies for that I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: Within lan network when user wants to access url the dns request is first' resolved by local dns server called as recursive lookup if record is not found in local DNS then dns request is further forwarded to isp name server or root server or Top level domain server this request is called iterative dns lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is a recursive process. The part where a client submits its DNS request is the "local resolver". It's a software-based service that runs on some kind of server.

If you find suitable software, it can run on any networked device. However, host configurations or product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.